# Trying to run Sikuli Slides Recorder, '$' doesn't work in cmd?

Tags: java, command

I'm trying to run this recorder and the instructions are to run the following line in a terminal:

$  java -jar sikuli-slides-1.5.0.jar record

When I do this, it tells me that $ is not recognized as a command. I have the latest versions of JRE/JDK installed, and I've already spent hours fiddling with the environment variables and making sure the paths are set correctly.

Running javac -version returns "javac 1.8.0_45". I'm not sure if this is correct, but I don't know what else to do. I've tried running the statement without the '$' at the beginning, but then it just tells me that it could not access the jarfile. Any advice?

Comment: I don't know if this means you're reading a shell command from unix/linux where the sigil is a $ and you're trying to run that or not... or if there's some defined reason you are to put a $ there? Usually that just means type `java -jar sikuli-slides-1.5.0.jar record` into the terminal.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize that I probably didn't need that $ in there. I am using Windows. When I run it without the $, however, it still tells me that it cannot access the jar file.

Comment: Does `java -version` work for you instead of `javac`? It most likely will, but just to be sure...; also are you running the command from the same directory it is in? Does the file require administrator privileges to run? Are you 100% sure you're spelling the name right?

Comment: Oh man, I'm a complete dunce. I was running it from a different directory. Thank you so much dude, lol.